# I can't make jar( Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I have pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.adept</groupId>
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>application</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.9.2</junit.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.16.1</jsoup.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21-ea+24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.adept.application.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.adept.application.Application</mainClass>
                            <!-- <mainClass>com.adept.application/com.adept.application.Application</mainClass> -->
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iGkO.png)
When a do java -jar application, i see
`Error: Could not find or load main class com.adept.application.Application Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application`

I tried to try various plugins to build in jar, but it still doesn't work. I prescribed manifests in the configuration of plugins, but it didn't work.I tried to write arguments in run configurations, but to no avail. I want to build it in a jar, but either JavaFX does not find it, or I'm a fool.
[linking libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd7Ob.png)

Comment: Did you try using the Maven assembly or shade plugin? If so, can you share your attempts with these plugins?

Comment: No, I didn't use it. I'm just starting to move in this direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the similar problem that fixed with this solution :

1-first create another class with a main method and then call the main method of your Application class that extends `Application`.

```
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.main(args);
    }
}
```

2-then add the shade plugin to the pom :

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation=
                                                     "org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Your_main_class_here</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

replace `Your_main_class_here` with path of App class in your case mabye: `com.adept.application.App`

video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyYb0GmtEX4

Comment: Thank you, creating a new Main class helped, and enabling maven.shade.plugin with its configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, then try to integrate your pom.xml with the following pom.xml. You do not need to specify any VM arguments. You need to adjust the main class `<mainClass>com.wedasoft.FxMultiMessageSender.FxMultiMessageSenderMain</mainClass>` in the javafx-maven-plugin and in the maven-shade-plugin in the pom.xml.

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.wedasoft</groupId>
<artifactId>FxMultiMessageSender</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <javafx.version>17</javafx.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- javafx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <release>11</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                    <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.wedasoft.FxMultiMessageSender.FxMultiMessageSenderMain</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.wedasoft.FxMultiMessageSender.FxMultiMessageSenderMain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Mainclass:**

```
package com.wedasoft.FxMultiMessageSender;

public class FxMultiMessageSenderMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.main(args);
    }

}
```

**JFX-Application-Starting-Class**:

```
package com.wedasoft.FxMultiMessageSender;

public class App extends Application {

    public static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "xxxxxxxx";

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private Scene primaryScene;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //createDatabase();
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting " + APPLICATION_NAME);
    }

}
```

**Example working JavaFX application with gradle**

https://github.com/davidweber411/SimpleJavaFxAppWithoutModules

**JavaFx Project Generator**

I created a project generator for private purposes, but you can download it from GitHub and use it too if you want:

https://github.com/davidweber411/JavaFxProjectGenerator

Note: It creates a Gradle project, not a maven project.